# Creating a matrix from the vectors listed in another vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have multiple vectors of equal length.

```
w1 <- c(0.61845, 0.65477, 0.68195, 0.71557, 0.74108, 0.76773, 0.78996)
w3 <- c(0.63003, 0.66249, 0.68596, 0.71628, 0.73922, 0.76488, 0.78470) 
w4 <- c(0.51598, 0.54827, 0.57069, 0.59755, 0.61832, 0.64179, 0.65878)
```

I have another vector containing the names of these vectors as characters.

```
w.list <- c("w1", "w3", "w4")
```

I'm trying to create a matrix of the vectors that are named in w.list.

```
     w1       w3       w4
0.61845  0.63003  0.51598
0.65477  0.66249  0.54827
0.68195  0.68596  0.57069
0.71557  0.71628  0.59755
0.74108  0.73922  0.61832
0.76773  0.76488  0.64179
0.78996  0.78470  0.65878
```

Context:
I'm automating a process, and I'm left with multiple vectors of equal length with the names w1, w2, w3 etc. However, the vector names do not necessarily follow a constant pattern; it could be w1, w3, w4. Therefore I can't easily define which vectors to add based on a simple formula. My actual data is much bigger.

Comment: Use a combination of `mget` and `as.data.frame`. Or `do.call(cbind, mget(w.list))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto The `do.call(cbind, mget(w.list))` worked, thank you for your help. If you submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still rather inexperienced and I don't know how to convert a comment into an answer, unless you mean submit as my own answer?

Answer (score 1):

The code `do.call(cbind, mget(w.list))` worked perfectly, many thanks to Ananda Mahto.